# Curiosity Rover (MSL): current coordinates

Tags: astronomy, nasa, solar-system-exploration

I'm looking for information on the **current coordinates** of [Mars Science Laboratory's](http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl/) Curiosity Rover.

I've only found the landing site coordinates `4.5895°S` `137.4417°E` ([Bradbury Landing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradbury_Landing)).

[image: Author:NASA/JPL-Caltech/Univ. of Arizona]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the layman interested in coordinates, go here and then click on the map link for any given day:

http://curiosityrover.com/tracking/drivelog.html

Then you're in the "Google Mars" view, with the rover's path displayed.  Of course, you could figure out something to get a list of coordinates in a standard map format.  But if you're looking for something simple, I suggest just pointing your mouse at the object you want and reading the coordinates in the bottom right of that screen:

[image: curiosity rover]

Answer (score 1):

From [Twitter](https://twitter.com/MarsCuriosity/statuses/331892131650236416):

> SPICE kernels for my location are available here
>   http://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/. For less technical locations, see
>   https://foursquare.com/marscuriosity

NASA is very open.  For example, you can get more than 50,000 raw images from the Curiosity mission at the [MSL website](http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl/multimedia/raw/), and it's updated as they come in.

Comment: If you still want more data, use [MSL Notebook](http://an.rsl.wustl.edu/msl/mslbrowser/).

Comment: [MSL forum](http://www.unmannedspaceflight.com/index.php?showforum=59) at UMSF - get news [from the horse's mouth](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/from+the+horse%27s+mouth).